# Neural Network for Learning Cut VS Uncut Grass

Tags: opencv, neural-network, computer-vision

I've got a script to take pictures like the one provided, with colored loops encircling either uncut grass, cut grass, or other background details (for purposes of rejecting non-grass regions), and generate training data in the form of a bunch of small images from inside the colored loops of those types of training data. I'm struggling to find which type of neural network that would work best for learning from this training data and telling me in real time from a video feed mounted on a lawn mower which sections of the image is uncut grass or cut grass as it is mowing though a field. Is there anyone on here experienced with neural networks, and can either tell me some I could use, or just point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try segmentation network. There are many [types of segmentation](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-segmentation/).

Mind that for neuron networks, training data is necessary. Your case (to detect cut and uncut grass) is considered special, which means existing models may not fit your purpose. If so, you'll need a dataset including images and annotations. There are also [tools for labeling segmentation images](https://github.com/topics/labeling-tool).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! That will give me things to look into.